# Does Google Analytics demographics functionality work for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I've been trying to implement the demographics functionality for Google Analytics on Android and iOS. First, I'm trying with Android. The rest of GA functionality is working properly on my app. I followed all the requirements, enabling analytics, all the options in the GA console, adding the code to my app ([Google Analytics demographics For Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901190/google-analytics-demographics-for-android-app)), etc.

Now I'm wondering if there is actually someone that managed to make this functionality work on mobile devices. I've searched a lot, not only Stack Overflow but also the rest of the Internet.

Is this functionality working for anyone at the moment? if so, would be very helpful if you could point me to the right direction to make it work.

Comment: Google certainly claims that this should work in their documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en#where (bullet points two and three).

Comment: @EikePierstorff, yes, I read that Google says that it should work but so far I haven't seen any developer that made it really work.

Answer (score 3):

For people who are struggling with the same issue, I contacted Google Analytics and they explained me the following:

> I have checked your case with one of our specialist and I would like
>   to share that if you have followed the steps correctly then the
>   changes would have been applied correctly. However, as the number of
>   sessions in your account are less, hence, there is a probability that
>   no data is recorded until it reaches above the required threshold.
>
> Let me share that thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a
>   report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual
>   users. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a
>   primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a
>   threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the
>   report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of
>   Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.
>
> Please let me know, If you need further clarification about the same
>   or have any doubts or questions about your AdWords account, all you
>   have to do is respond to this email and I will be glad to assist you
>   through.

So, if you want to make Google Analytics Demographics work on Android or iOS you need a lot of users (they didn't specify how many).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of mobile phone you are using, like for example older version of android doesn't support dynamic language. but some new version can access the website completely.

Comment: But I'm testing on new devices of Android and it doesn't work. Did you make this work on new Android devices?

Comment: if it won't work on your current android, try downloading an app called "gAnalytics" on play store.